# Pthread RWLock on MAC Deadlocking but not on Linux?

Tags: macos, pthreads

I've been experimenting with rwlock's on Mac and am experiencing something that seems to me shouldn't be happening. There's some weird combination of using read/write locks with recursive read locks that is deadlocking, but shouldn't be.

I posted the code on pastebin because it's more than just a snippet. The way this code is written shouldn't deadlock, and indeed doesn't when running on linux. Why does this deadlock on a mac?

http://pastebin.com/Ui9iS1ke

Any ideas?

Comment: how many cores do both machines have?

Comment: the mac has two cores, the linux machine has 3 cores.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PThread RWLock Deadlocking with Recursive Locks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3984276/pthread-rwlock-deadlocking-with-recursive-locks)

Answer (score 1):

See the bug I reported with apple.

https://bugreport.apple.com/cgi-bin/WebObjects/RadarWeb.woa/7/wo/0blX77DJS8lBTTxVnTsNDM/5.83.28.0.13

Answer (score 1):

Here's the open radar bug.

http://openradar.appspot.com/8588290

Answer (score 0):

Aaron: I just ran into this.  I found that one can workaround this by using thread local storage.  Create a wrapper around the rwlock that increments a thread local key:

```
@interface ReadWriteLock : NSObject {
    pthread_key_t readKey;
    pthread_key_t writeKey;
    pthread_rwlock_t rwLock;
}

-(void)lockRead;
-(void)unlockRead;

-(void)lockWrite;
-(void)unlockWrite;

@end
```

Then increment the readKey using `pthread_setspecific` when you call lockRead, decrement it when you call unlockRead, only `rd_lock` when the key goes from 0 to 1 and only `rw_unlock` when the key goes from 1 to 0.  Copy this for the writeLock logic.

Since the `pthread_setspecific` and `pthread_getspecific` are thread-local, you don't need to lock around access to these. Make sure to call the appropriate pthread creation / initialization functions in `init`, and make sure to dispose of all of the pthread_* members in `dealloc`.

Unfortunately I can't give you the full source to my solution, but the above method works ( I've tested it heavily ).

Comment: I also created a c wrapper around rwlocks for this situation.